# Amcharts : How can I add customized data to exported image?

Tags: charts, amcharts

I would like to make custom data like date, filter criteria a part of exported image with amcharts.

Is this possible? If  yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is not part of the amCharts output (the chart/legend etc) will normally not be included in the exported image.

However, there is an option to generate system reports including your charts, which let you also include custom headers, text, and whatever other information you want. You will have to define a layout file, a JS object that describes the look and contents of your report.

Have a look at the demo http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/e7616f8b5e5e0049fb96368000a17951

```
// Save as single PDF and offer as download
this.toPDF(pdf_layout, function(data) {
   this.download(data, this.defaults.formats.PDF.mimeType, "amcharts.pdf");
});
```

Or the docs
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/export-charts-advanced/
(look for "Seamless system reports on the fly")